# Writing query in controller instead model

Tags: codeigniter, model-view-controller

I wanna ask about if we write query in controller instead model. does it have any effect? such as load data become slower or others?

the data that i want to use is over 1000.

if not, what makes the load of data slow in web.

like the ajax request is needed 4-5 sec, and some is until 1 minutes

Comment: Queries are often performed in the controller, its generally faster.

Comment: @Programnik queries are *not* typically performed in the controller when using *mvc*, and running queries in a controller would only be a *negligible amount faster* - not because of the query but rather the overhead from loading another php class (the model).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is virtually no difference between running a query in a controller or a model except for the small (negligible) amount of overhead a model adds (if it were me I wouldn't worry about it). If you want to adhere to the MVC design pattern, database queries are typically done in the model, not the controller. But this is more of a stylistic thing in CodeIgniter as it is not strictly enforced as it is in other frameworks that use ORM.

With that being said, if you are experiencing long execution times I would recommend not getting all the data at once, and instead using load more, pagination, datatables, or a similar system to reduce the amount of records selected at once to something more manageable depending on your acceptable execution/response times.

You can test what works in your situation best by setting benchmark points: https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/benchmark.html

Comment: you can also see: https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/results.html `unbuffered_row()`

Answer (score 0):

I have been working with CodeIgniter for some few years and what I have realized is to properly do your queries in models.

The idea of MVC is about code separation where the M(Model) handles or does the heavy liftings of the application which mostly relates to databases, the V(View) does the presentation that is where users of the system get to interact with the application and the C(Controller) acts as a messenger or intermediary between the Model and the View.

This releases the controller from lots of processes so that it doesn't have to query from the database, try to upload lots of data before then showing it on a view.

I always use the (I call it the little magic) `{elapsed_time}` and `{memory_usage}`to check how my application work per whatever logic I implement, you can give it a try.

I think this helps.